# Reading a txt.file in C++ with vectors and matrices including commas and square brackets between the numbers

Tags: c++

The following example is a part of data that I should read in C++. But I don't know how to read matrices and vectors which has square brackets and commas between the numbers. Do you have any such example or an idea on how to read this?

Thanks a lot.

Example data:

```
[40, 12, 100, 3, 0.05 ,12 ,6]

[[3850.6, 1481, 592.4],
[4989.4, 1919, 767.6],
[3335.8, 1283, 513.2],
[5142.8, 1978, 791.2],
[5116.8, 1968, 787.2],
[4460.3, 1715.5, 686.2],
[3727.1, 1433.5, 573.4],
[3248.7, 1249.5, 499.8],
[4704.7, 1809.5, 723.8],
[3127.8, 1203, 481.2],
[3225.3, 1240.5, 496.2],
[3403.4, 1309, 523.6]]
```

Comment: 1. fstream
2. >> operator
3. regex

Comment: Have a go and if you have any problems post a new question with your code, and a more specific question about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a file you need this:

1. [**std::ifstream**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) - to open and read file
2. [**std::getline**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) - for reading it line-by-line
3. [**std::istringstream**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/?kw=istringstream) - for line parsing
4. [**std::stod**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/) - for double parsing

Here is sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// example data that imitates real file
std::string example_data = R"([40, 12, 100, 3, 0.05 ,12 ,6]

[[3850.6, 1481, 592.4],
[4989.4, 1919, 767.6],
[3335.8, 1283, 513.2],
[5142.8, 1978, 791.2],
[5116.8, 1968, 787.2],
[4460.3, 1715.5, 686.2],
[3727.1, 1433.5, 573.4],
[3248.7, 1249.5, 499.8],
[4704.7, 1809.5, 723.8],
[3127.8, 1203, 481.2],
[3225.3, 1240.5, 496.2],
[3403.4, 1309, 523.6]])";

// extractor operator to read vector from stream
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<double>& vec)
{
    //#1 - check if it starts from '['
    char c;
    is >> c;
    if (c != '[')
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Invalid character : ") + c + 
                                   " when parsing vector of double");
    //#2 - get the line till ']'
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(is, line, ']'))
        throw std::runtime_error("Error parsing vector of double");

    //#3 - parse values inside '[' and ']'
    std::istringstream lstr(line);
    std::string value;
    while (std::getline(lstr, value, ','))
        vec.push_back(stod(value));
    return is;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& m)
{
    //#1 - check if it starts from '['
    char c;
    is >> c;
    if (c != '[')
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Invalid character : ") + c + 
                                   " when parsing matrix of double");

    // parse matrix line-by-line
    while(true)
    {
        std::vector<double> tmp;
        is >> tmp;
        m.push_back(std::move(tmp));
        // if matrix finihed, c should contain ']', else - ','
        is >> c;
        if (c == ']')
            return is;
        if (c != ',')
            throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Invalid character : ") + c + 
                                       " when parsing matrix of double");
    }
}
// display vector
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& t)
{
    os << "[";
    for (auto it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); ++it)
        os << (it != t.begin() ? ", " : "") << *it;
    os << "]";
    return os;
}
int main() 
{
    // open sample data
    std::istringstream in(example_data);
    // to use real file - comment previour and uncomment next line
    //std::ifstream in(your_file_name);

    std::vector<double> vec;

    in >> vec;

    std::cout << "Vector: " << vec << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> m;
    in >> m;

    std::cout << "Matrix: " << m << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Vector: [40, 12, 100, 3, 0.05, 12, 6]
Matrix: [[3850.6, 1481, 592.4], [4989.4, 1919, 767.6], [3335.8, 1283, 513.2], [5142.8, 1978, 791.2], [5116.8, 1968, 787.2], [4460.3, 1715.5, 686.2], [3727.1, 1433.5, 573.4], [3248.7, 1249.5, 499.8], [4704.7, 1809.5, 723.8], [3127.8, 1203, 481.2], [3225.3, 1240.5, 496.2], [3403.4, 1309, 523.6]]
```

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/m7icKP)